# JSplitPane divider custom arrow signs

Tags: java, swing

I want to make **custom and bigger arrow** for my JSplitPane and also put some space between the up and down arrow.

My current JSplitPane image

[image: my current JSplitPane image]

Comment: please see how to ask questions before asking and posting questions.

Comment: @karan I need 10 reputation to create an image. this is not a mistake, it's a stackoverflow restrication

Comment: The arrows in your image look large.  How much bigger to you want the arrows to be?

Comment: You will most likely need to modify the LAF via [BasicSplitPaneUI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicSplitPaneUI.html) and/or [BasicSplitPaneDivider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicSplitPaneDivider.html)

Comment: @copeg I use these two class and I could pretty much do most of the working but I just have some problem with drawing polygon because I don't have experience in graphic 2d. could you please help me with that ? here is my project ->  [link](https://github.com/m3hdiii/CustomJSplitUI)

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I know it's ok but our customer insist in making it bigger, I did most of the work but I have problem in drawing, here is the project -> [link](https://github.com/m3hdiii/CustomJSplitUI)

Answer (score 1):

> I just have some problem with drawing polygon because I don't have experience in graphic 2d.

Assumming g2d is your `Graphics2D` object then some basic code to get you started would be:

```
Polygon triangle = new Polygon();
triangle.addPoint(0, 0);
triangle.addPoint(15, 30);
triangle.addPoint(30, 0);
g2d.setColor( Color.RED );
g2d.fill( triangle );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to know your users will always use the Windows Look & Feel, then you can simply make the divider larger:

```
splitPane.setDividerSize((int) (splitPane.getDividerSize() * 1.5));
```

That will increase the arrow size (up to a limit of about * 2), but not the space very much.